Why is my form being submitted automatically when I reach certain page?
I've created a multi step form and using react-hook-form, zod and shadcn. What I did is I created a next button that will increment by 1 every complete step. But when I my currentFormPage reach 4 the processForm automatically gets called.
What I did is I created a conditional Button that will render depending on the currentFormPage
Calendar.tsx
const [currentFormPage, setCurrentFormPage] = useState(0);

const goToNextPage = async () => {
  setCurrentFormPage((step) => step + 1);
};

const processForm = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  }

const form = useForm<Inputs>({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchemaData),
    defaultValues: {
      title: "",
      email: "",
      fullName: "",
      department: "",
      dateOfEvent: "",
      purpose: "",
      startingTime: "",
      endingTime: "",
      doesHaveDryRun: "no",
      dryRunDate: "",
      dryRunStart: "",
      dryRunEnd: "",
      doesHaveTCETAssitance: ["tcet"],
      tcetOtherAssitance: "",
      meetingType: "meeting",
      meetingTypeServices: [],
      meetingTypeServiceLink: "",
    },
  });

return (
 <Form {...form}>
              <form
                onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(processForm)}
                className="space-y-8"
              >


 {currentFormPage === 1 && (
     <>
      //...set 1 one of question
     </>
  )}

{currentFormPage === 2 && (
     <>
      //...set 2 one of question
     </>
  )}

{currentFormPage === 3 && (
     <>
      //...set 3 one of question
     </>
  )}

{currentFormPage === 4 && (
     <>
      //...set 4 one of question
     </>
  )}


 {currentFormPage === 4 ? (
        <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
      ) : (
        <Button type="button" onClick={goToNextPage}>
           Next
         </Button>
       )}
      </form>
</Form>
)


This can be solved by calling e.preventDefault() inside your processForm() function so the form is not automatically submitted when the button is first rendered on the screen when the count reaches 4.
More about it here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11894534/22178475
